# Best way to create Observable, using from, in RxJS 5.x?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Now that we have "lettable" operators, how should we go about creating an `Observable` from another?

When I try to do:

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
const source = Observable.from(someOtherStream)
```

I get the error `Observable.from is not a function`, which makes sense, because `from` is now something else that needs to be imported separately.

I don't want to do

`import 'rxjs/add/observable/from'` anymore due to the prototypal problems there.

What I ended up doing was:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from'

const myNewStream = from.call(
  Observable,
  someOtherStream
)
```

But this really feels "hacky" for some reason to me.  Does anyone have any better ways of going about this?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: You could use the [bind operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/), then you could write `Observable::from(someOtherStream)` which is pretty nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lettables are behind `rxjs/operators` [here's the write up on it](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md).

For `from` you should be able to import it without importing Observable.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';

const prom = new Promise(res => setTimeout(
  () => res('promise'), 3000
));

from(prom).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[webpackbin example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KyxE7F4y0P9XCq4ZA21)

Using `from` this way allows you to `pipe()` to the lettable operators.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

const prom = new Promise(res => setTimeout(
  () => res('promise'), 3000
));

from(prom).pipe(
  map(x => x.split('').reverse().join(''))
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[webpackbin example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KyxZ7nKTBlSnkWyCDjG)

Comment: So there's no need to give it the `Observer` context?

Comment: Correct, then you can pipe to the lettables instead of chaining https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KyxZ7nKTBlSnkWyCDjG

Comment: Perfect. Worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is misunderstanding what `from` does. It's just a function that takes a "stream" (that's Observable, Promise, array, ...) and creates an Observable from it.

This means you use it just like any other function:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from'

from(someOtherStream).pipe(...).subscribe(...)
```